# Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, json, facebook-android-sdk

I am working with Android Facebook SDK and wanted to get a friends list. I have created an "AsyncTask" for doing such a thing. I am pasting my `doInBackgroundMethod` here.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String jsonResponse;
        try {
            jsonResponse =     Factory.getFacebook().request(Utils.LOGGEDIN_USER_FRIENDS);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Utils Code

```
public static final String LOGGEDIN_USER_FRIENDS = "me/friends";
```

The problem I am running in to is that it is returning an empty jsonResponse for the first time the application runs. When I open my app the second time I am getting the JsonResponse. But for the first time however I am getting empty jsonResponse.

Can any one help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was easy... It was messed up by creating a String variable in a Factory. Later on, the same day I saw that, and called the AsyncTask built in method ***get*** which provides the result in the same thread.